# ¿Como puedo conseguir la imagen que esta en un ImageView para editarla?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview, bitmap

En este condigo estoy tomando la imagen desde los recursos, lo que quiero es tomar la imagen que esta en el imageView o cualquier imagen que ponga en el ImageView, como podrán ver uso `BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.f);` para buscar la imagen a la cual le quiero poner el texto, pero como dije antes quiero tomar lo que sea que ponga en el ImageView

```
    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageViewtext);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.f);
    Bitmap.Config config = bitmap.getConfig();
    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();

    Bitmap newImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(width,height,config);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newImage);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,0,0,null);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setTextSize(20);

    canvas.drawText("Hola",0,25,paint);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(newImage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como se menciona [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26865787/get-bitmap-from-imageview-in-android-l/27030439#answer-27031932), puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```java
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
```

Comment: Lo hice pero me da este error : tempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.getBitmap()' on a null object reference

Comment: ¿Puedes dar alguna información sobre el error?

Comment: tempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.getBitmap()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

Obtèn el `Bitmap` del `ImageView`, pero recuerda que el ImageView con id `imageViewtext` debe ser cargado en el layout de tu Activity:

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageViewtext);
...
...
Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Comment: Sigue  dandome problemas

Comment: Trata de agregar siempre que error se muestra, en este caso me parece que el problema no es como obtener el Bitmap del ImageView, el problema se debe a que tal vez no tienes el ImageView en el layout, si es una Activity revisa en el layout que carga mediante el método setContentView(...) , en este layout  debes tener un ImageView con id "imageViewtext".

Comment: Podrías escribir el codigo completo para saber en qué estoy mal?

Comment: Agrega tu clase donde cargas la imagen primeramente.

Comment: Todo ese código que puse al principio es clase y si tiene un imageView en el layout, también tiene el setContentview